# Why does this clearly failing condition, not fail?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

While trying to debug a TextField issue, I noticed that `onValueChange()` was being endlessly called. I dug deeper and found this interesting condition. `Value` and `it` are the same object but the condition seems to succeed and lets `onValueChange()` be executed. Does anyone have insight on why this is the case?
[debug console with condition going into function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afjig.png)

I didn't expect this condition to succeed. I haven't typed anything and it continues to evaluate itself

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/input/TextFieldValue#equals(kotlin.Any)) method sources (probably, you will need to download them) during your next debug, most probably this condition checks to not produce to your handler excess, repeating data that you have already handled. P.S. please send your conclusion as answer here for clearance.